# Is it possible to connect to a tfs 2005 server from vs2012?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, tfs-2005

We have a TFS 2005 server with some old code and I got VS2012. Should it be possible to connect to the TFS 2005 server from VS2012? Or do I need to install TFS explorer 2010?

Comment: Have you discovered any workarounds for this?

Comment: Sort of, moved to git :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS Compatibility Matrix - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997788.aspx

According to the above link, neither VS2012 nor VS2010 can connect to TFS 2005.

You may need to use the MSSCCI Provider.

Comment: The matrix is wrong, you can connect using VS2010, but not VS2012. I installed VS2010 team explorer and got access to the repository.